# Can't get closest to work

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following code which works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var xhr = false;

    func_two();

    $('.button_one').click( function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 

        if ($("#textbox_one").val().length > 0) {
            func_one( $("#textbox_one").val() );
        } else {
            func_two();
        }
    });

    function func_one( phrase ) {
        xhr = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'url here',
            data: '{phrase: "' + phrase + '"}',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function( data ) {
                $("#inner_div").empty();

                if( data.d[0] ) {
                    $.each( data.d, function( index, row ) {
                        $("#inner_div").append( "dynamic data goes here" );
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function func_two() {
        $('#inner_div').empty().append( "static data goes here" );
    }

});
```

This works fine as I am directly specifying which tags cause an effect and which tags get affected.  The problem is that these div's are infact widgets or gadgets, and I need to allow the user to have more than 1 of these widgets or gadgets on the screen at at any given time.  Things seem to go totally wrong when I try this because "I assume" of the use of an id for the controls and divs.

So, I have tried using classes instead, which seem to work in the test code here:

```
$(this).closest('.main_div').find('.sub-div').text("data goes here");
```

However, when I try to apply this code to the original code above, it does not seem to work.  It gives me an `Cannot call method 'closest' of undefined` according to Chromium's Developer tools.

The code which I have tried which does not seem to work looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var xhr = false;

    func_two();

    $('.button_one').click( function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 

        if ($("#textbox_one").val().length > 0) {
            func_one( $(this), $("#textbox_one").val() );
        } else {
            func_two( $(this) );
        }
    });

    function func_one( that, phrase ) {
        xhr = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'url here',
            data: '{phrase: "' + phrase + '"}',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function( data ) {
                $("#inner_div").empty();
                that.closest('.outer_div').find('.inner_div').empty();

                if( data.d[0] ) {
                    $.each( data.d, function( index, row ) {
                        that.closest('.outer_div').find('.inner_div').append( row.column );
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function func_two( that ) {
    that.closest('.outer_div').find('.inner_div').append( "static data goes here" );
    }

});
```

The HTML looks like this

```
<div class="outer_div">

    <div class="inner_div">
        results go here
    </div>

    <div class="footer_div">
        <input type="button" class="button_one" />
    </div>

</div>
```

Can someone please help me implement the test code into the original code?

Comment: Is your button element, inside of the main div?

Comment: If `that` is `undefined`, then you're not passing anything to `func_one`.

Comment: @Bryan Moyles, yes the button element and the sub_div are within the main_div.

Comment: Tested this with a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/cR9Zj/1/), and even if the button is deleted, it works just fine for me ?

Comment: @adeneo, for me the button gets deleted in your example?

Comment: Updated the question with requested data.

Comment: It does get deleted, that's the point, but the variable `that` still is not "undefined", it does'nt suddenly change because the element is no longer there, or because you use it in another nested function.

Comment: @adeneo, so what you're saying is that there is a bug in chromium for reporting it as undefined?

Comment: I'm pretty sure @adeneo is saying that there's a bug somewhere in your code that isn't represented in the question. This code works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/J6ePC/

Comment: @cliffsofinsanity - Yup, that's exactly the point. There is no reason the `that` variable should be undefined in a nested function if it was defined to begin with. Something else is clearly interfering, and the answer below seems like no more then a temporary fix to me, but thats just my unprofessional opinion, and the fiddle above seems to demonstrate the same.

Comment: I've rewritten the entire question, I'm hoping this makes the issue a little more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out, I believe your button is being deleted, and there's no longer a reference to that element. By storing a reference to the targetted sub div, THAT stays in the context of what you're trying to do :)

```
function func_one( that ) {
    xhr = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'some url here',
        data: 'data to post here',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function( data ) {
            var column_elements = [];

            for(var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                column_elements.push(data.d[i].column);
            }

            $('.sub_div', that.parents('.main_div:first')).text(column_elements.join(", "));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Even if the button is deleted, it wouldn't cause the `that` variable to become `undefined`.

Comment: That's the reason why I'm only using that, before the actual element is deleted... Please read the code

Comment: We did, and it makes no sense ?

Comment: Please visit http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page, you'll learn everything you need from there. OP, please trust my knowledge, and test my implementation of your function. I promise you that it will bring you closer to your desired outcome

Comment: This solution seems to work.  However, the button element is outside the sub_div, but within the main_div.

Comment: Can you please attach a sample of the html to your original question? I'd be more than happy to sculpt my answer according to your structure, if I'm able to see what that is :)

Comment: @Bryan Moyles,  I've added further details including a little HTML to the original question above.

Comment: I've updated my code according, feel free to try it out. I don't know exactly how your json object looks, but I made the best guess I could to provide the data as you've asked for it

Comment: Yep, I had read your original answer. It simply made no sense that removing the button from the DOM would cause any change to the `that` variable (or the jQuery object for that matter), causing it to be `undefined`, and resulting in the error denoted in the question.

Comment: I've rewritten the entire question, I'm hoping this makes the issue a little more clear.